# Vue JS - Trigger Method if input lost focus

Tags: vue.js

Quick question about Vue JS.
On my website, I have got a shopping cart and the user can enter any quantity. I am saving this quantity to the database table when he enters it...

**issue is**, the input field keeps firing save method every single digit of user types. For example, if the user types 123, the save method called 3 times. 1 and 12 and 123

I just want to call this save method when this input loses the focus, so I can save only once, not every single digit.

**Component**

```
Vue.component('product-counter', {
props: ['quantity'],
data: function () {
    return {
        count: this.quantity
    }
},
template: `
        <div class="input-group ">
          <input  v-bind:value="quantity" v-on:input.focus="$emit('input', $event.target.value)"  type="text" class="form-control col-2">
        </div>
        `
 })
```

**Component Call**

```
                <product-counter 
                             v-bind:productcode="item.productCode"  
                             v-bind:quantity="item.quan" 
                             v-on:input="item.quan=updateItemQuantity($event,item.productCode)" 
                             v-on:increment-quantity="item.quan=updateItemQuantity(item.quan,item.productCode)" 
                             v-on:decrement-quantity="item.quan=updateItemQuantity(item.quan,item.productCode)"></product-counter>
```

**Vue: Method**

```
        "updateItemQuantity": function (totalquantity, pcode) {
       if (totalquantity != '') {
           ... Update Database...              
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're listening to the `input` event, which is triggered every time the value of the input changes, so every time a character is typed or removed.
Instead, you should listen to the `blur` event, which only fires when an input loses focus.

You can pass this along through your component, the same way you pass through the input event.

TLDR: Couple UpdateItemQuantity to **v-on:blur** instead of **v-on:input**, and make sure to $emit the `blur` event from your products-counter component.

---

Tip: Separate the client-side state (item.quan) and your server-side 'state' (your database) into two different methods. You want the value to reflect what the user is typing in real-time (`input`), which conflicts with what you want for updating the database (not real-time, only on `blur`). Otherwise you may get cases where users can't see what they type, as item.quan is never updated.

Answer (score 5):

I think you just need to use **@change** instead of **@input**

Comment: Finally, I thought no one will suggest. This is most generic solution.

Comment: Using 'change' does make more sense for this use case. 'blur' will always fire even if input field got focus, but user did not change value and klicks somewhere else.
'change' will only fire when the value has changed.

Answer (score 2):

It could be that you should use blur event.
Vue:

```js
    new Vue({
        el: "#app",
        data: {
            quantity: ''
        },
        methods: {
            printConsole: function () {
                console.log('blured');
            }
        }
    })
```

html:

```html
        <div id='app'>
            <input v-bind:value="quantity" v-on:blur="printConsole" type="text" class="form-control col-2">
        </div>
```

see jsfiddle for reference: https://jsfiddle.net/erezka/h8g62xfr/11/

blur will emit your change only after you focus out of the input